# if statement is not working not giving a output

Tags: php

```
<?php
$age1 = isset($_GET['age1']) ? $_GET['age1'] : "";

if ($age1 <= "18")
{
    $sql = 'select * from events where type_id='.$id.' and id = "1"';
    $tid = mysqli_query($conid, $sql);
}
else
{
    $sql = 'select * from events where type_id='.$id.'';
    $tid = mysqli_query($conid, $sql);
}
?>
-----------
<tr>
    <td class="style1">Age:</td>
    <td class="style2"><input type="text" name="age1" id="age1" class="form-control22" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="style1">Event Type:</td>
    <td class="style2"><select name="event_id" class="ddl" id="event_id" onchange="geteventprice()">
                       <option value="0">--Select Event Type--</option>
                       <?php while($evt= mysqli_fetch_object($tid))
                        {
                            echo   '<option value="'.$evt->id.'">'.$evt->name.'</option>'; } ?>
                    </select>

    </td>
</tr>
```

After else statement is not working...

Comment: its not working is not a good explanation.

Comment: are these two different files?

Comment: if statement is not working because you perform Arithmetic operation on a string value i.e "18"

Comment: where is OP though?

Comment: ok @Faraz comparison operation fails in OP question, why isn't the else case getting executed?

Comment: Is `type_id` is integer type in mysql

Comment: @Faiz99 An exception occur when execute  if

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operation did not work on string value. update your code like:

```
 if ($age1 <= 18)
                    {
                        $sql = 'select * from events where type_id='.$id.' and id = "1"';
                        $tid = mysqli_query($conid, $sql);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql = 'select * from events where type_id='.$id.'';
                        $tid = mysqli_query($conid, $sql);
                    }
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine on strings as well. read manual "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically."

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sql = 'select * from events where type_id='.$id.'';
if (isset($_GET['age1']) <= 18)
{
    $sql.= 'and id = 1';
}
 $tid = mysqli_query($conid, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conid));
?>
```

How about using this way. It is more clean and easier to understand. You can see if there is problem with query also